# What's new in iPhone SDK 3.2?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Apparently it is available ([www.apple.com/ipad/sdk/](http://www.apple.com/ipad/sdk/)), but I can't find a changelog... Not used to apple.com though.

Does anybody have detailed information? What I would like to know is : are there any new API or did they only add iPad stuff?

**Edit** : I am not asking for implementation-level details, I would just like to know the features added for iPhone, if any. Do you really think this falls under the NDA? Pragmatically,do you really think Apple would track down, kick-out and/or sue the developer who gives the information? I don't see how it would hurt Apple's interests... Everybody has public APIs, even MS for Job's sake (ah ah - sorry could'nt resist). Well anyway maybe there is somebody authorized to tell the world (somebody from Apple?) somewhere on this Internet...

PS. I have no account at Apple, because I know that the previous SDK do not have the APIs I require for my app, so I work on other mobile platforms for the moment. This is why I cannot access the information myself.

**Edit-2** :
Here is some information I gathered on the net:

- **SDK 3.2 beta is not supported by iPhone (only iPad).** As far as I am concerned, this settles things up, I am not interested in iPad dev.
- **It is now possible to use VoIP over a 3G connection** iCall have updated their app for iPhone and [officially announced it](http://www.icall.com/about/news/#22). But this is not part of the SDK beta, is it?
- **external displays are supported**

I am putting this question under community wiki, in case some of you would like to expand this list (keeping in mind that NDA bound developers shall not contribute), or correct false or inaccurate information.

Comment: Having looked over the API diffs, there is new stuff.  But anyone who has access to the API also has agreed to an NDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `UIGestureRecognizer` becomes public. [This](http://iphonedevwiki.howett.net/index.php?title=UIGestureRecognizer) is the info about this class when the class was still private.
- `UIBezierPath` becomes public
- `CoreText.framework` (and `NSAttributedString`) becomes public.
- `UIGetScreenImage` is renamed to `UICreateScreenImage` (but still not documented).
- There is built-in spellchecking (via the `UITextChecker` class).
- `CATextLayer` is now available.
- The ICU headers are now available along with the SDK. `NSRegularExpressionSearch` (ICU regular expressions). The ICU version is upgraded to 4.2.
- Applications can share files.

(Ref: http://1985.pe.kr/archives/185)

Answer (score 7):

Go to that URL and select "Get Started", log in, make sure iPhone SDK 3.2 beta is selected, and check out the "What's new in iPhone OS 3.2" link.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for API diffs? I found these just under the link to download the new SDK beta. If you have access to that (NDA as epatel said) it might answer your questions.

Answer (score -2):

Note that you can get into the iPhone developers SDK area with an Apple Developer Account, which is free - you have to request entry into the iPhone Developer Program, also free.

You only have to get a paid account if you want to test on the device or distribute in the store.

Comment: You can't access the beta/restricted SDK releases without a paid developer account. I logged in with my expired paid account and could only see 3.1.